# is there mysql corelib site for building queries?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Maybe i have the wrong context but...

Is there a corelib site for mysql like http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/ for ruby on rails RoR?

Would be nice to have 1 stop shop. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there isn't any documentation like corelib for MySQL that I know if, there is the [official MySQL Reference Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/) which is very good.